# Create Opportunities and activities created by user joined report

Tags: joined-reports

I'm new with joined reports and I'm trying to create a joined report that shows the number of opportunities and activities created by each user.

Previously, I've created 2 report separately, one about opportunities created by each user and another aboud activities created by each user but when I try to create a joined report I can't able to show the same info.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to achieve the requirement.

I've created 2 report types, the first one, Users with/without Opportunities, and the second one, Users with/without Activities.